# How do I make synchronous calls in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, synchronous

I am beginner to react js and I am working on a small feature to reset table data in one of our UI projects.

Current functionality:

- There is a save button which saves all the overrides(i.e., saves changes made to the original table data for this id in another table called overrides table) in the DB and
- a reset button to clear these saved overrides(i.e., deletes the overrides data from the overrides table for this id ).
- Once the user clicks on Reset button on the UI, the current code does an api call to the backend to clear all the overrides in the table data.
- And the users have to refresh the page to see the up-to date data.

**Current code:**

```
const handleClearData = () => {
    clearData({})
  }
```

The new requirement is to refresh the data after clearing the overrides in the table i.e., I have to call the refetchData call after doing a reset. something like below:

```
const handleClearData = () => {
    clearData({})
    refetchData()
  }
```

`clearData` uses a common function(code below) which is a Async call. And `refetchData` also uses a similar common function as below.

```
function fetchResponse (url, fetchOptions) {
  const fetchFailureResponse = error => {
    return Promise.reject(
      Error(`${error.message}`)
    );
  };


  return fetchMethod(url, fetchOptions)
    .then(parseSuccessResponse)
    .catch(fetchFailureResponse)
    .then(parseResponse => {
      // code to parse the error response
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });
}
```

when I hit the reset button, I can see that sometimes the `refetchData`  call is made even before the `clearData`  call, so even though my table overrides are deleted, the refreshed data(from the refetchData call) is stale and my table on the UI doesn't reflect the new data.

I need to ensure that I have to call the refetchData once the clearData call is completed. I tried adding a timeout but 1/2 seconds timeout isn't helpful and a timeout more than that is weird(i.e., it takes 5 seconds for the data to get refreshed after making the reset which is spoiling the user experience).

Can I please get some help on how to achieve this? Been stuck on this for quite sometime.

Edit: clearData does a delete api call which is internally using the `fetchResponse` method. refetchData is a get api call which is also using the `fetchResponse` method.

Comment: `clearData({}).then(() => refetchData())`? I assume clearData returns a promise (you didn't actually show what clearData does)

Comment: The solution is not to change the code to become synchronous. The solution is to change the code to handle the asynchrony.

Comment: clearData does a delete api call which is internally using the fetchResponse method. so on success it is returning a parsed response from `parseSuccessResponse` method.

Answer (score 0):

async

assuming clearData is returning a Promise.

```
clearData({}).then(() => refetchData())
```

checkout async await if you want clearer syntax

```
async function handlecleardata() {
   await clearData({})
   await refetchData()
}
```

Comment: `clearData` is returning a parsed json response. using then on json is giving me `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')`

Comment: that means clearData is not async eg not returning a promise. can you add the clearData method, likely your bug is in this function. async methods are the way to tell the script to wait for something to happen before continuing.